# How to understand multiple peaks in FFT analysis?

Tags: fft, resonance

In FFT analysis, it is often seen that there are several peak frequencies with integer times of frequencies. For example, in the figure below, there are peaks at $0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8$.

The FFT figure below is transformed from the time history of force coefficient $C_{Y2}=F_y/(\rho D U_m^2/2)$ and displacement $Y_2$ on $Y$ direction of a cylinder immersed in a disturbed fluid and attached to a spring.

[image: Fig. 1 FFT spectra of vibration displacement and force]

- How to understand this pattern?
- If you are familiar with vibration, how to explain these vibration data?

Comment: Where does $Y_2$ come from, and what does $C_{Y_2}$ mean? Could you give more context around the "vibration" experiment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at [harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic) of the fundamental. There's a lot of [literature](http://www.dspguide.com/ch11/5.htm) available to [read](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_do_harmonics_signify_in_the_FFT_spectrum_of_a_signal) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the system you are investigating, there can only be (standing) waves of a certain length. Mostly the wavelength is determined by the physical size of your system. The term resonance is often associated with harmonics.
Where did you get your data from?

Comment: Then the harmonics are dependent on the mass and the spring constant. The system can be described with a differential equation which then can be transformed into the frequency domain. With that you should be able compare the measured harmonics with the calculated ones.